# How to edit Yith Woocommerce subcription text "/20 month"

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have little problem where I can edit this on the plugin folder.
[Price Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq6xz.png)

I want to edit it to 29/month not $29/29 month because its look like 29 months.

here are the folder inside the plugin

[Folder List Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpf8F.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should see YITH's documentation page, there they have shown every step of installation and settings of this plugin. You can change the month segment in settings page as per your need. You can also change the $ sign to your currency.

Check this image [image: YITH Detailed Product Image]

and this link of YITH's documentation page:

https://docs.yithemes.com/yith-woocommerce-subscription/category/free-settings/

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. :) I really appreciate it. I remove some codes on the backend to meet my requirements.